# Formidable Forms Update Field From Another Form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins

I have a form that im trying to use to update another form with Formidable Forms.

Im trying to create a simple inventory adjustment form. My form has a lookup field that looks at the main form for unique name in inventory. Then has another field that gets the entry id. The third field is a number field set default value as a lookup for the quantity also based on the unique name. All this works fine when first set up. The code i put into a Code Snippet seems to update the Quantity when i look at the entries, however when i got back to the adjustment form, the quantity field still shows the original quantity value. If i go into the back end and edit the value, that value will show. Shome how this code is updating the backend but the short codes used to pull it into the forms does not get updated.

Any help?

```
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'frm_update_entry_in_other_form', 30, 2);
function frm_update_entry_in_other_form($entry_id, $form_id){
if ( $form_id !== 14 ){
    return;
}

$entry_id = $_POST['item_meta'][79]; // Entry ID from main form.
$update_value = $_POST['item_meta'][85]; // A Calulation from form that adds adjustment value and a lookup value of Quantity based on Entry ID

$field_id = 83; // Quantity field on main form
$new_value = $update_value;// change 'Approved' to the value you want to set the field in your main form

$added = FrmEntryMeta::add_entry_meta( $entry_id, $field_id, null, $new_value );
if ( ! $added ) {
    FrmEntryMeta::update_entry_meta( $entry_id, $field_id, null, $new_value );
}
```

}

Comment: I was not able to resolve this issue through code, however if anyone is looking to do something similar Formidable Forms has an API you can use to send information to another form. If the API does not work for your site, go to the receiving form setting and set "Use Honeypot to check entries for spam" to Off and uncheck "Check entries for spam using Javascript"              https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/formidable-api/#kb-update-an-entry